# Need assistance with text based game specifically output code when a button is pressed on a certain level

Tags: javascript, html, jsfiddle

I need assistance with text based game to specify output code when a button is pressed on a certain level.

How can I write the code so that when I pressed the same button on a different level it will execute a different line of code?

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <body>

        <head>

            <script>

                let level = 1
                if (level === 1) {
                    alert(level + '. You are walking down a path and see a shadowy figure emerge from the woods, what do you do?')


                    var button = document.createElement("button");
                    button.innerHTML = "Threaten";
                    var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
                    body.appendChild(button);
                    button.addEventListener("click", function() {
                        alert("something happens");

                    });
                    var button = document.createElement("button");
                    button.innerHTML = "Flee";
                    var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
                    body.appendChild(button);
                    button.addEventListener("click", function() {
                        alert("something happens");
                    });
                    var button = document.createElement("button");
                    button.innerHTML = "Attack";
                    var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
                    body.appendChild(button);
                    button.addEventListener("click", function() {
                        alert("something happens");
                    });


                };



            </script>

        </head>

    </body>

</html>
```

Please tell me what I am doing wrong, because I can't find answers.

Comment: If we had more context we could help you.

Comment: Ok so I want to have a small amount of actions that can be executed for a prompt and then depending on the action you press it will spawn new buttons that execute different actions that the first ones

Comment: Also when the way the prompt switches is that a level counter increases and an if statement checks the value

Comment: You may want to read about [switch statements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch).